# Defer template loading when using ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to defer loading of my main controller/template (AppController) until I load the users profile from a service.

For all navigation routes, I'm using $routeProvider with resolve

```
.when('/edit/:editId', {
    templateUrl: 'editTemplate.html',
    controller: 'EditController' // this is a child controller of AppController
    resolve: {
         currentUser: ['svc.user', function(userSvc) { return userService.getUser(); }]
    }
// and so on..
```

But for AppController I'm using

How can I do a resolve for AppController? Essentially, I'd like a userService.getUser() which returns a promise to finish executing before AppController is actually run, I'm not sure how to do this using ng-init though (or if it's possible, i thought only expressions not promises could be executed).

Thanks for any help/assistance.

Comment: See this video http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-resolve/ and good demo for your exact issue here: https://github.com/johnlindquist/angular-resolve

Comment: Thanks charlietfl - so the hidden 'app' promise is what I'll need.

Thanks!

Comment: no...should resolve the promise from the service. Look how is done in demo: https://github.com/johnlindquist/angular-resolve/blob/master/client/js/app.js

Comment: yes, but you can also put a module in there too I found. So in their case they pass the reference to app. In my code, I'm using minified code with requirejs, so i'm using string literals. So I have a 'app.core' module. I use 'app.core' : { // resolve stuff } which ensures that when it gets the core, it also caches the user.... unless i've got it totally wrong ?!? hope not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in this video: http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-resolve/

You should try:

```
.when('/edit/:editId', {
  templateUrl: 'editTemplate.html',
  controller: 'EditController' // this is a child controller of AppController
  resolve: {
     currentUser: ['svc.user', function(userSvc) { return userService.getUser(); }]
     app: function ($q) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve();
                return defer.promise;
     }
}
```

Comment: should be resloving the promise of `userService` not creating an arbirary one