# Defer template rendering until controller execution completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, ngcloak

I have a template and a controller. There is some code in controller executed whenever the state is changed to the respective view. How can I make sure none of the components of template gets rendered until the controller completes its execution. I already know about resolve - promise as answered in this question -

[Defer template loading when using ng-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633686/defer-template-loading-when-using-ng-controller)

What I am looking for is a way to defer template rendering until my controller does it's job. I know about ng-cloak as well but it din't work when I applied it on the root element of my template. I may have a wrong understanding of it.

Here is the code -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center animated fadeInDown">
            <h3>Welcome to ***********</h3>

            <p>No authentication found. This may be because you are logged out.
            </p>

            <p>Please click the following button to authenticate you using portal.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center animated fadeInDown">
            <br/>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_self"
               href="/portal/oauth/authorize?client_id=cms-web-view&response_type=token&redirect_uri={{returnToUri}}">Authenticate
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center animated fadeInDown">
            <br/>
            <p class="m-t">
                <small> © 2015</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>-->
```

And the controller -

```
define(['layout/module'], function (module) {

    'use strict';

    module.registerController('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $location, $state, $log, $http, $window) {

        $scope.returnToUri = $location.absUrl();

        var hash = $location.hash();
        $log.info($location.absUrl());
        if(hash.indexOf('access_token') > -1) {
            var extractRegex = /access_token=([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)&/;
            var result = extractRegex.exec(hash);
            if(result.length > 1) {
                $log.debug('Found access token in hash, redirecting to the app.', result[1]);
                localStorage.setItem('oauthToken', result[1]);
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + result[1];
                $state.go('app.dashboard');
            } else {
                $log.error('access_token not extractable via regex from hash', hash);
            }
        } else if(hash.length > 0) {
            $log.debug('Hash didn\'t contain the access_token', hash);
        }

        // Circular redirection - An intermediate page is necessary
        //$window.location.href = '/portal/oauth/authorize?client_id=cms-web-view&response_type=token&redirect_uri=' + $location.absUrl();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `ng-cloak` and post your controller & markup? As that is definitely the way to go

Comment: if your controller is returning an array of results, you could use ng-show and check the length of the array as condition to show the respective content

Comment: My controller checks for token, if found it will redirect to dashboard, if not sets the redirect uri for authentication. So when there is a token, I don't want the template to render for a sec and then eventually redirect to dashboard state